# To create Function for Write-Output

Tags: powershell

Can we create a function to log the message  where the function contains `Write-Output`?

```
Function LogWrite
{
    Write-Output '"...."
}
```

The scenario is similar like the output information for logging would be like

> LogWrite "Hello" -append "./file.txt"

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the answer provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your wanting to do is add text to a file, it would be better to use `Add-Content`. Something like this:

```
Function LogWrite(input){
    Add-Content -Path c:\path\to\file.txt -Value input
}
```